# How to read response in serial port communication in sequence before next command C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, serial-port

I'm writing a program in C# which deals with serial port communication, writing commands and reading response. I send about 50 commands to the COM Port. On my screen, I need to display the commands sent and response received in sequence. For example, Command 1 - Response 1, Command 2 - Response 2, and so on. But my program displays the 50 commands first and then 50 corresponding responses. This is my DataReceivedHandler function :

```
private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
      Thread.Sleep(2000);
      SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
      data = sp.ReadLine();
      setTextInReplyBox(data);
}
```

The setTextInReplyBox function displays the values into textBox. I tried using async await but it didn't work.

Comment: First: remove that `Thread.Sleep`

Answer (score 0):

1.defining the serial port in event is not OK.

2.using Thread.Sleep() makes the program faulty.

3.make a queue for saving messages for sending process.

4.use asynchronous programming for getting a better result.

so we do based on the below approach:

A. Create a queue to hold your commands. Enqueue all 50 commands before starting the communication.

B. When a response is received, dequeue the next command from the queue and send it.

C. Instead of using Thread.Sleep(2000) (which blocks the thread), use an asynchronous approach.

D. Subscribe to the DataReceived event and handle it asynchronously.

so the program will look like this:

```
    private static SerialPort _serialPort;
    private static Queue<string> _commandQueue = new Queue<string>();

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Initialize your SerialPort settings
        _serialPort = new SerialPort("COM1", 9600);
        _serialPort.DataReceived += DataReceivedHandler;
        _serialPort.Open();

        // Enqueue your 50 commands
        EnqueueCommands();

        // Start sending commands
        await SendCommandsAsync();

        // Clean up
        _serialPort.Close();
    }

    private static void EnqueueCommands()
    {
        // Enqueue your 50 commands here
        _commandQueue.Enqueue("Command1");
        // ...
        _commandQueue.Enqueue("Command50");
    }

    private static async Task SendCommandsAsync()
    {
        while (_commandQueue.Count > 0)
        {
            string command = _commandQueue.Dequeue();
            _serialPort.WriteLine(command);

            // Wait for response asynchronously
            await WaitForResponseAsync();
        }
    }
    private static async Task WaitForResponseAsync()
    {
        // Implement your response handling logic here
        // For example, read the response using _serialPort.ReadLine()

        // Simulate waiting for response (replace with actual logic)
        await Task.Delay(2000);

        // Display the response (use your setTextInReplyBox function)
        string response = "Response for " + command; // Replace with actual response
        Console.WriteLine(response);
    }

    private static void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Handle data received (if needed)
    }
```

Comment: And on top of all your suggesting here, the user has noted this is a web based application. This means that the client side browser will have to call a web method, or one needs to setup a web socket, and that suggests then using SignalR.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal Apologies. it's a winforms application. I've edited that now. Thanks.

Comment: In this line - string response = "Response for " + command; // Replace with actual response , where does the response come from ? Did you mean using something like _serialPort.ReadExisting() ? or is there any other technique. I'm new to this. Thanks.

Comment: @Shiwa the response string is for confidence about that the command is sent.